# Laravel database seeder, setting specific values laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-seeding

I am trying to populate my databases and have a parent `status` table and a child `server_statuses` table. This is a one-to-many relationship.

The issue i'm running into is that the statuses table only has 3 values and they need to be set to specific values (`success, warning, danger`). Larvaels documentation doesn't go into much depth on how to accomplish this.

Im also not sure if the seeding is the reason im getting the error, posted below. If it isnt the seeding I was thinking I could possibly hand enter the 3 values within PHPmyAdmin then run my DB seeder. I will also post my migration as well as the seeder files.

Any thoughts on a solution to this error?

Current error when running the seeder:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constrai
ENCES `statuses` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `server_statuses` (`server_id`, `status_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (20, 4, 2018-07-03 12:21:05,
```

Migrations:

```
 Schema::create('statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('key');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

 Schema::create('server_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('server_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('server_id')->references('id')->on('servers')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Seeder factory(deletd what I was trying for the Status because it was a terrible attempt at a solution):

```
$factory->define(Status::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    return [
        'key' => ,
        'status' => 
    ];
});

$factory->define(ServerStatus::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'server_id' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 20),
        'status_id' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 3)
    ];
});
```

Comment: This error is because you are inserting entries into `server_statuses` with `status_id`  which not present in `status` table.

Comment: But cant I do this because of it being a foreign key referencing `id` on statuses?

Comment: First make entries in `status` with id 1 to 3 and then run command to insert data in `server_statuses`.

Comment: That is what I have been doing is going to PHPmyAdmin and adding the 3 values then running my DB seed. I figured that's what the issue was, How could I make it so that my seeder seeds those 3 values so I no longer have to do this?

Comment: Which version of laravel you are using?

Comment: I am using larvael 5.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is because you are inserting entries into `server_statuses` with `status_id` which not present in `status` table. First make entries in `status` with id 1 to 3 and then run command to insert data in `server_statuses`.

Based on your last comment. The way to seed database from array.

Create a seeder class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\Status;

class StatusSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run() {
        DB::table('status')->delete();
        $statuses = [
            ['key' => 1, 'status' => '1'],
            ['key' => 2, 'status' => '2'],
        ];
        foreach ($statuses as $status) {
            Status::create(array(
                'key' => $status["key"],
                'status' => $status["status"],
            ));
        }
    }

}
```

And add its entry in default `DatabaseSeeder.php`

```
public function run()
    {
         $this->call(StatusSeeder::class);
    }
```

Run the seeding process by `php artisan db:seed`. For more information, visit [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding).

Comment: That worked, my issue was that I thought I had to use a factory and call it a certain number of times I didn't know I could do the seeder logic within the seeder class. Thank you so much!